# Should git repo have three refs

Tags: git, github

I recently detached the HEAD from my git repo and was able to remove it by just force pushing my code to  main however now I'm seeing in `git reflog` that my most recent commit has multiple refs when I would think it should just be `HEAD`

`git reflog` output

```
6a5c0e3 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: commit: Remove git test comment.
37c6a90 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from main to main
37c6a90 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from main to main
37c6a90 HEAD@{3}: commit: Make calculation use Sheet builder
86bc423 HEAD@{4}: commit: Testing git integrity
1cdb617 HEAD@{5}: commit: Fix sheet buttons for CalculationBuilder
a2d3086 HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from main to a2d30861060c439995f7daa906064340d01e2424[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

I would think that `Refs` should just be `main` or `origin/main` right?

Comment: about the `git reflog` part : also note that you would see the same names when running `git log` or `git show`, the fact that these references point to commit `6a5c0e3` at the time you run your commands has nothing to do with `git reflog`. The constants are : `HEAD` will always point at "the current commit", `origin/HEAD` will always point at "the default branch on the remote" (which is `origin/main` in your current setup, and will probably stay so)

Comment: Multiple named heads can point to the same committish. This is useful when comparing multiple branches to see where HEAD is or where the log graphs converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think possibly you have misunderstood some terminology.

- `HEAD` is just where git records which commit you currently have checked out. Your working copy will always have `HEAD` pointing at some particular commit (except for in a completely new repo with no commits in it yet).
- `main` is the name of a branch. A branch in git is just a pointer to a single commit; the history of the branch is calculated by following the "parent" pointers backwards through each commit.
- `origin/main` is your local cache of where some other copy's branch called "main" points; often, that's the same commit, because the other copy is a central server you've kept your code in sync with.
- `origin/HEAD` is the "current commit" of the other copy; for a central server, that generally tracks the "default branch" of the repository.

So, if what you currently have checked out is the branch called "main", which is the same as the remote branch called "main", and that's the default branch on the remote server, all four refs will point to the same commit. That's perfectly normal.

When you get a "detached HEAD", it just means you've checked out something other than a branch - a tag, or a particular commit by its hash. In that case, and only that case, the current commit would be pointed to by `HEAD` but not by any named branch.

Comment: Thank you, this explained it well!